# How to make request for a Elastic search url using java application?

Tags: java, http, elasticsearch

When i browse the url of elastic search it works, when i try to connect through the code, it returns a 400 bad request error. When i request for www.google.com, it returns `'200 OK'`. What could be the problem?

here is my code:

```
      url = new URL("http://192.168.1.68:9200");
      httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
      httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
      out = new OutputStreamWriter(
      httpCon.getOutputStream());
      int responseCode = httpCon.getResponseCode();
      String responseMessage = httpCon.getResponseMessage();
      System.out.println(responseCode);
      System.out.println(responseMessage);
      if (httpCon.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Connection Successful");
      }
      else {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Connection Error!");
      }
      out.Close();
```

Comment: Did you try "GET" instead of "POST" ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing in any search parameters... for example:

`url = new URL("http://192.168.1.68:9200");`

should be

`url = new URL("http://192.168.1.68:9200/_search?q=whatever+you+want");`

or you should post your JSON formatted query by writing to the out stream and then closing it (but you still need to tag /_search onto your URL.)